# 画像の重ね合わせでフォルダ指定で複数ファイルを読み込めるようにしたい

Tags: python

画像の重ね合わせについてどなたかご教授お願い致します。

```
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image1 = pydicom.dcmread('C0.dcm') #Startshotは3枚以上画像が必要です
image2 = pydicom.dcmread('C45.dcm')
image3 = pydicom.dcmread('C135.dcm')

image_sum = image1.pixel_array + image2.pixel_array + image3.pixel_array
img = plt.imshow(image_sum)
img.set_cmap('gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.margins(0,0)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.savefig("Starshot.tiff", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

というコードで画像の重ね合わせができるものに対して、フォルダを選択すれば同じように重ね合わせができるようにしたいと思っています。そこで、

```
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = pydicom.dcmread(r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ\Star") 
image_sum = images.pixel_array
img = plt.imshow(image_sum)

img.set_cmap('gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.margins(0,0)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.savefig("Starshot.tiff", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

と変更してみたのですが、

```
  File "C:\Users\tanim\untitled11.py", line 11, in <module>
    images = pydicom.dcmread(r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ\Star")

  File "C:\Users\tanim\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 861, in dcmread
    fp = open(fp, 'rb')

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\tanim\\OneDrive\\デスクトップ\\Star'
```

とエラーが発生し、うまくいきません。
修正すべき点はございますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ\Star` がフォルダだからではないでしょうか。`pydicom.dcmread()` の場合、引数には DICOM ファイルを指定する必要があります。

Comment: なるほどそうだったのですね。では複数のファイルを選択するのは難しいのでしょうか？おそらく同様の理由からだとは思いますがおもいますが、`pydicom.filereader`や`pydicom.read_file`等試してみたのですが、うまくいかないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` でフォルダ内の DICOM 画像ファイルのパスを取得、`pydicom.dcmread()` で 1 ファイルづつ読み込んで、`sum()` で `pixel_array` を重ね合わせます。

```py
import os
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dicom_dir = r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ\Star"
image_sum = sum([
  pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)).pixel_array
  for f in os.listdir(dicom_dir)
  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)) and f.endswith('.dcm')
])

img = plt.imshow(image_sum)
img.set_cmap('gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.margins(0,0)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.savefig("Starshot.tiff", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

Comment: 無事合算できました。いつもありがとうございます。解説までしていただき本当に助かります！